# DNase annotations of Drosophila melanogaster

Tags: drosophila, gene-annotation, dnase

I am familiar that the [RedFly database](http://redfly.ccr.buffalo.edu/) provides annotations for 1,458 sites in the genome of *Drosophila melanogaster* subject to cleavage by DNase I. It seems the vast majority of those annotations come from the original FlyReg database originally reported in 2005, which merged with RedFly early on. I have looked, but not found any additional sources of annotations of the Drosophila genome of DNase cleavage sites. I wanted to ask, to be sure, if there are no additional studies / experiments which record DNase annotations in the Drosophila genome outside of the ones recorded by RedFly.

Answer (score 2):

I think that DNAse-seq is no longer the favored assay for chromatin accessibility.

These days, I believe [ATAC-seq](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6499308/) is favored, or even [single-cell variants](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9371440/) of ATAC-seq. (links to drosophila papers)

I can't comment on a general Drosophila regulatory database beyond what you already know about, beyond what's obvious via google ([here](https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/47/D1/D828/5133668), [here](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34751401/)).

Comment: Very useful answer but are you sure it's no longer favored? 2021: "DNase I is still the reagent of choice for TF footprinting, which can determine the location of TF binding sites due to the protection of the site by the TF itself." https://doi.org/10.1038/s43586-020-00008-9

Comment: @arara interesting, I don't have access to the review unfortunately so it's hard for me to evaluate. I suspect that there is a subtle distinction between "TF binding sites" and "chromatin accessibility". Chromatin accessibility is a rather more generic phenomenon. What I would bet is that ATAC-seq is more common these days in large part because it's easier methodologically. But I could readily accept that DNAseI is a more diagnostic, less biased reagent at the single molecule level (or for e.g. one locus probed on a Southern blot). But I'm also not an expert in the field!